# Understanding the composition law of maximum entropy

Tags: information-theory, maximum-entropy

Shannon derived the principle of maximum entropy from 3 assumptions. One of those assumptions is the composition law.

In other words, he derived that maximizing the probability weighted log of probabilities is the only assignment of probabilities that satisfies these 3 criteria.

The composition law (informally) states that it should be possible to "split up" the probability space in different ways, without changing the total weighted entropy.

My conjecture is: If we want to choose a quantity $Q$ that we will maximize w.r.t. the probability distribution, then if we require that this maximizing distribution is the same regardless of how we partition the probability space, it must be the case that $Q$ is the probability weighted log of probabilities (i.e. the entropy).

Is this requirement equivalent to the composition rule? Or does it at least result in the composition rule?